# stringByEvaluatingJavascriptFromString (iOS method, what is Android equivalent?)

Tags: java, php, android, ios

In an iOS app, I used

```
stringFromJavaScript = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavascriptFromString:@"document.getElementById(\"image\").getAttribute(\"src")"];
```

To get the src directory of the image that was being displayed on the webView. I want to do the same for Android. What are my options?

Basically the intent is to capture the path so that I can email this same picture...

ie.

```
"picture.php?image=%@",stringFromJavascript
```

This way, that same image would be loaded when the user clicks the link, or posts it to facebook etc.

Comment: Something like this may be the right track, however I would like to get the element as a String to use in the code    http://lexandera.com/2009/01/injecting-javascript-into-a-webview/

Comment: The silly part is that `WebView.loadURL()` apparently uses `stringByEvaluatingJavascriptFromString()` internally when the URL scheme is `javascript`. https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/webkit/BrowserFrame.java#L262

Comment: You could use this method in Android via reflection, please visit 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/17830417/2442753

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Yeah, I miss this method greatly in Android ;)

To execute JavaScript and get response you can do as follows:

1. Define JavaScript callback interface in your code:

   ```
   class MyJavaScriptInterface {
       @JavascriptInterface
       public void someCallback(String jsResult) {
            // your code...
       }
   }
   ```
2. Attach this callback to your WebView

   ```
   MyJavaScriptInterface javaInterface = new MyJavaScriptInterface();
   yourWebView.addJavascriptInterface(javaInterface, "HTMLOUT");
   ```
3. Run your JavaScript calling `window.HTMLOUT.someCallback` from the script:

   ```
   yourWebView.loadUrl("javascript:( function () { var resultSrc = document.getElementById(\"image\").getAttribute(\"src\"); window.HTMLOUT.someCallback(resultSrc); } ) ()");
   ```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you so much! this works fantastic! too bad its so much more tedious than the iOS method! Though i suppose a bit more flexible! :)

Comment: +1 because you explained the idea clearly, i could not understand the concept from the other websites...

Comment: Hi,i am getting Uncaught TypeError, please check the error.[INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'someCallback' of undefined", source:  (1)