# Android, getting html content in my app

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

I need to get some properties of an html page which is loaded in a webview.
Something similar to what is here: [stringByEvaluatingJavascriptFromString (iOS method, what is Android equivalent?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10304680/stringbyevaluatingjavascriptfromstring-ios-method-what-is-android-equivalent)

So I have a JavaScriptInterface:

```
class MyJavaScriptInterface {
    @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
    public void jsCallback(String jsResult) {
        // your code...
        Log.d("Debug", jsResult);
    }
}
```

ant then here is the JS I use to get the string I need:

```
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(), "HTMLOUT");
    webView.loadUrl("javascript:( "
            + "function () { "
            + "var htmltag = document.getElementsByTagName(\"html\");"
            + "var dataStr = htmltag[0].getAttribute(\"some-data-property-i-need\"); "
            + "console.log(window.HTMLOUT);"
            + "window.HTMLOUT.jsCallback(dataStr); } ) ()");
```

now in the console I see this traces:

```
06-02 01:14:06.409: V/CallNative fired:(26789): objc://domReady
06-02 01:14:06.464: I/Web Console(26789): undefined at null:1
06-02 01:14:06.480: E/Web Console(26789): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'jsCallback' of undefined at null:1
```

and I have no idea why "window.HTMLOUT" is undefined.
Please note that it was working at a point and then I modified a bit the JS part but I still cannot figure it out what could be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

JS code can be executed after the whole page is loaded, have a try at this way:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        // Call JS code here
    }
});
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, "<html></html>", "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```

If previous method does not work, please have a try at `HTMLOUT.jsCallback(dataStr)` instead of `window.HTMLOUT.jsCallback(dataStr)`.

Comment: I tried... same problem... well a bit different: 06-02 01:45:01.847: E/Web Console(325): Uncaught ReferenceError: HTMLOUT is not defined at null:1

Comment: @Ciprian I've modified my answer.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply, I tried that thing and it is the same, I can't get it working. But I've noticed that if I call something like this: webView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(), "HTMLOUT");
webView.loadUrl("javascript:( " + "function () { })()"); after the loadUrl of the page I want I get the stuff. But I still don't understand why...