# Android Service reads localStorage?

Tags: java, android, cordova, local-storage

I have developed a PhoneGap application for Android. 
The application is composed by the *webapp* (HTML/jQuery) and a *background service* (Java code) that's started by the webapp.

This webapp writes to **window.localStorage** like

```
    <script>
       window.localStorage.setItem("name","MyName");
    </script>
```

Is it possible to read this **name** that is in the localStorage from my Java code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is possible.  To execute JavaScript and get response you can do as follows:

Define JavaScript callback interface in your code:

```
class MyJavaScriptInterface {
    public void someCallback(String jsResult) {
         // this will be passed the local storage name variable
    }
}
```

Attach this callback to your WebView:

```
MyJavaScriptInterface javaInterface = new MyJavaScriptInterface();
webView.addJavascriptInterface(javaInterface, "HTMLOUT");
```

Run your JavaScript calling window.HTMLOUT.someCallback from the script:

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:( function () { var name = window.localStorage['name']; window.HTMLOUT.someCallback(name); } ) ()");
```

Note - `window.localStorage['name']` is the same as `window.localStorage.getItem('name')`

[This post here on stackoverflow helped me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10304680/stringbyevaluatingjavascriptfromstring-ios-method-what-is-android-equivalent)

You might need to use `super.webView.addJavascriptInterface` or `super.addJavascriptInterface` to add the interface.  You might need to use `super.webView.loadUrl` or `super.loadUrl` to invoke this.  It all depends on where you are going to be calling these from.

Comment: @Ross I know this is an old topic, but could you point me to a repo that has this method fully implemented in a Cordova plugin? I'm trying to modify the Cordova Device plugin to use this code, but I keep getting errors. I know barely any Java. I would love to see a working example of this code. :D

Comment: @user1002379 I'm not aware of any plugins using this approach.  Have you seen these SO posts [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727763/communication-between-android-java-and-phonegap-javascript) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14031635/android-4-2-1-webview-and-javascript-interface-breaks?lq=1)?  Are you trying to read the values provided by the Cordova device plugin in Java?

Comment: But webview is not accessible from a Service

Answer (score 3):

Use cordova-plugin-nativestorage plugin to read localstorage in android java file.

it's for IOS,Android Plateform

this plugin use nativeStorage

Cordova Syntax:

```
NativeStorage.setItem("reference", obj, setSuccess, setError);
function setSuccess(obj){
}
function setError(obj){
}
```

Anroid JAVA:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MainActivity", MODE_PRIVATE);
System.out.println("********---------    shared pref values...   " +  sharedPreferences.getString("myid", "no value"));
```