# Android WebView getContentHeight() always returns 0

Tags: android, android-webview

I am implementing an WebView such that it can resize its height according to the content height. I tried to do the following:

```
WebView view = new WebView(context);
view.loadData(htmlString, "text/html", "utf-8");

view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        Log.d("2", view.getContentheight() + "");
        // Set the height of the webview to view.getContentHeight() here?
    }
});

Log.d("1", view.getContentHeight() + "");
```

Where htmlString is a String of HTML format.

However both the two Logs return 0.

I am not sure if I am doing the right thing. How can I know the content height then set the height of the WebView accordingly?

Answer (score 13):

this is because the `onPageFinished` callback means the WebView has finished reading the bytes from the network, just that. At the point `onPageFinished` is fired the page may not be even parsed yet.

If your webview's height is set to wrap_contents then you could do something like this:

```
WebView v = new WebView() {
    @Override
    public void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int ow, int oh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, ow, oh); // don't forget this or things will break!
        Log.d(TAG, "WebView height" + getContentHeight());
    }
};
```

If your webview is not wrap_contents then one option is to do what josedlujan suggested in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23095807/2977376) to this question and fetch the height from JavaScript.

Another option would be to use the deprecated `PictureListener`:

```
webview.setPictureListener(new PictureListener() {
    int previousHeight;
    @Override
    public void onNewPicture(WebView w, Picture p) {
        int height = w.getContentHeight();
        if (previousHeight == height) return;
        previousHeight = height;
        Log.d(TAG, "WebView height" + height); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

you can obtain the height and width with javascript from the webview.

```
WebView view = new WebView(context);
view.loadData(htmlString, "text/html", "utf-8");
view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
view.setSaveEnabled(true);
view.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(), "HTMLOUT");
view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
  view.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.getContentHeight
        (document.getElementByTagName('html')") 
    }
});
view.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,htmlString,"text/html","utf-8,null");

   }



 class JavascriptInterface{
   public void getContentHeight(String value){
       if (value != null){
          webviewContentHeight = Integer.parseInt(value);
             Log.d(LOG_TAG("result from js"+webviewContentHeight);
             Toast.makeText(activity,"Content Height is:"+webviewContentHeight,
                     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
       }
   }
```

Comment: get height method not getting Called!!

Answer (score 2):

Here is working code to get webview scrollheight on view finished loading:

```
WebView webviewPageTest=new WebView(this);
webviewPageTest.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
class JsObject {
    @JavascriptInterface
       public void toString(String jsResult) {
           Log.v("scrolH:",jsResult);
           //use this if you need actual onscreen measurements 
           //float webViewHeight = (Integer.parseInt(jsResult) * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
       }
    }

webviewPageTest.addJavascriptInterface(new JsObject(), "HTMLOUT");
webviewPageTest.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl("javascript:( function () { var h = document.body.scrollHeight; window.HTMLOUT.toString(h); } ) ()");
        }
    });

this.addContentView(webviewPageTest, params);
```

worked of here [Łukasz Sromek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10349530/812637) and josedlujan above and here [android dev docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String))

Answer (score -3):

> You can do this by providing some delay in onPageFinished()

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    int contentHeight = webView.getContentHeight();
                    int viewHeight = webView.getHeight();
                    Toast.makeText(context, "*** " + contentHeight + " - " + viewHeight, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }, 500);
        }
    });
```