# InAppWebView getContentHeight always returns 0 on Android

Tags: flutter, webview, flutter-inappwebview

I use `InAppWebView` to display a web content in our app.
To ensure that it only takes the necessary space I listen to the `onLoadStop` callback to then set a `SizedBox`s height.

There I try to get the content height:

```dart
final height = await controller.getContentHeight();
```

But it always returns 0.

On iOS I always get the right height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that Android calls the `onPageFinished` callback for the Android Webview too early. Answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23093513/android-webview-getcontentheight-always-returns-0).

Adding

```dart
if (Platform.isAndroid) {
   await Future.delayed(
      const Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
   );
}
```

solves the problem and

```dart
final height = await controller.getContentHeight();
```

returns the correct height.