# Android counterpart for 'stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString'

Tags: javascript, android, html

Supposedly I have

```
    NSString *html = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('infoPageID').innerHTML"];
```

in iOS. It returns string value. Now, can any body help me how can I use that function in android to be able to get the value of the html i will load my webview. As per research, it looks similarly this way in android, but I don't know if it right.

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('infoPageID').innerHTML");
```

I just want to know how I will be able to set the value of that in string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [stringByEvaluatingJavascriptFromString (iOS method, what is Android equivalent?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10304680/stringbyevaluatingjavascriptfromstring-ios-method-what-is-android-equivalent)