# Android: problem with debugging javascript in webview

Tags: android, android-webview

I have some javascript running in WebView, and I want to receive console messages about errors in JS.
In accordance with the instructions at http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/debugging.html I overrided methods

`WebChromeClient.onConsoleMessage(String message, int lineNumber, String sourceID)`

and

`WebChromeClient.onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage cm)`,

redirecting messages to logcat. In android 2.1 it works well, but in android 2.2 none of this methods are  called.

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Experiencing the same issue on stock HTC Desire HD/Android 2.2.

Comment: I have HTC Legend. It seems like HTC-specific problem, because on emulator all works fine.

Comment: probably same issue at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538516/javascript-console-log-on-htc-android-devices-and-adb-logcat

Answer (score 7):

It seems that HTC disabled console.log on Android 2.2 devices. check out this post:

[How to display console.log() output in PhoneGap app using Eclipse and HTC Desire HD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847290/how-to-display-console-log-output-in-phonegap-app-using-eclipse-and-htc-desire)

Answer (score 6):

I just tested on 2.2 (level 8).  It's working fine.  Not sure why you're not seeing it.  I would validate the setting of ChromeClient.

js contains...

```
console.log("Hello World");
console.error("Serious");
```

ChromeClient contains

```
    @Override
public void onConsoleMessage(String message, int lineNumber, String sourceID) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.v("ChromeClient", "invoked: onConsoleMessage() - " + sourceID + ":"
            + lineNumber + " - " + message);
    super.onConsoleMessage(message, lineNumber, sourceID);
}

@Override
public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage cm) {
    Log.v("ChromeClient", cm.message() + " -- From line "
            + cm.lineNumber() + " of "
            + cm.sourceId() );
    return true;
}
```

Log contains
03-16 15:53:12.309: VERBOSE/ChromeClient(595): Hello World -- From line 24 of file:///android_asset/base.js
03-16 15:53:12.309: VERBOSE/ChromeClient(595): Serious -- From line 25 of file:///android_asset/base.js

Comment: I have similar code. On emulator it works well. But on device it does not.