# How to see Console log output in samsung galaxy S2

Tags: javascript, android, debugging, mobile

I am using samsung galaxy s2 version 2.3.3, i open a web page in android default web browser.

In the Page i put console.log("some info") to debug the page, but i am unable to see the console.log output in my device.Please help me in this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: may be [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538516/javascript-console-log-on-htc-android-devices-and-adb-logcat) link help you

Comment: @Ram:Thanks but i tried this before asking this question i.e i  enter about:debug in address bar , i am not seeing anything

Comment: see this which worked for my s2 standard with no hassle http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538516/javascript-console-log-on-htc-android-devices-and-adb-logcat

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Warning: No Longer Working!

This solution appears to no longer be functional as the web tool has not been maintained over the years.

---

Try using [JSConsole.com](http://jsconsole.com). It's a remote debugger for JavaScript. The setup is basically just injecting a `<script>` tag in your page.  Once connected you can read all the `console.log` calls from the remote page on JSConsole, as well as execute commands on the client.

#### Steps to Setup

1. Go to [JSConsole Home Page](http://jsconsole.com/), and type `:listen`.
2. Copy the resulting `<script src="http://jsconsole.com/remote.js?..."></script>`.
3. Drop that into the page you need to debug.
4. Open your page in any browser (phone, tablet, desktop, etc).  All `console.log` calls will be forwarded to the JSConsole.com window.

There are more details plus a couple of useful videos on the [**Remote Debugging Page**](http://jsconsole.com/remote-debugging.html).

Comment: Thanks For your answer.But i don't know how to do these steps.More helpful if you could help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

In Two ways we can see console.log messages

1. Using WEINRE
2. Using Eclipse

**Method 1:**

Use WEINRE remote WEb Inspector in REmote. it is a nodejs package. Steps to install WEINRE.

1. Install nodejs
2. run this command to install weinre :`npm install -g weinre` (for
   MAC`sudo npm install -g weinre`)
3. Then launch WEINRE: `weinre --boundHost -all- --httpPort 8082`, here
   8082 is port number where WEINRE is launched.
4. Then add the following script tag in the HTML/web page you want to
   debug or to see console messages, `<script
   src="http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8082/target/target-script-min.js#weinredemo"></script>`
5. `xx.xx.xx.xx` is the IP of your machine.
6. `weinredemo` is the ID for your page and you can use any of our own.
7. Then open the page , where you want to see console messages in any mobile device.
8. Open this page  any webkit
   browser,`http://localhost:8082/client/#weinredemo`
9. There go to console tab and see the messages.

**Method 2:**

1. please connect your mobile via USB drive and see the phone listed in ECLIPSE and need to install ANDROID ADT plugin for eclipse to see the console messages in Eclipse.