# How to display console.log() output in PhoneGap app using Eclipse and HTC Desire HD?

Tags: eclipse, cordova, android

I am developing PhoneGap webapp where I use some javascript, and sometimes I need to see console.log() output. I can easily see it when running in Chrome, it also works fine, when running this app in Android emulator - output of console.log() shows up in Eclipse LogCat window. But when I run this app on my HTC Desire HD, LogCat just shows some Android-specific output, but nothing coming from my webapp.

Anybody has idea how to display console.log() output from PhoneGap-app running on HTC Desire HD ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

See the PhoneGap mail list [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/FiALy94hwTE). Also, two stackoverflow threads [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4860021/android-problem-with-debugging-javascript-in-webview) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538516/javascript-console-log-on-htc-android-devices-and-adb-logcat).

It seems that console.log is disabled on HTC devices running Android 2.2.

The best workaround I've found is to use [weinre](https://github.com/apache/cordova-weinre), which intercepts the console.log to show the output in its desktop browser console.

**Update**: PhoneGap 1.3.0 now supports console.log directly to LogCat from the HTC Evo without any workarounds. (The same program doesn't work with PhoneGap 1.1.0)

Comment: The 1.3.0 workaround in the guts of PhoneGap is to change DroidGap.init to call:

    // Set the nav dump for HTC
   settings.setNavDump(true);

Comment: A lot of data seems to get dumped to the LogCat, so I'd suggest adding a filter, and filter by the Log Tag, "CordovaLog". 

Then from your PhoneGap Javascript you can simply call console.log("Message"); to output a message to the log.

Answer (score 32):

Another workaround is to use console.log() [jsconsole.com](http://jsconsole.com/remote-debugging.html)

Comment: WARNING: The console log approach doesn't work on all devices. Especially some HTC phones with 2.3 versions.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that console.error gets higher priority than console.log , and appears in the adb logcat output for both emulator devices and real devices connected via USB.

Answer (score -2):

Try this filter:

adb logcat PhoneGapLog:V *:S

It will only show console.log and phonegap specific output.

Comment: There is nothing from PhoneGap in the log, so the filtering won't help anything..