# capture logcat errors in phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

Does anyone know how to capture logcat Errors in phonegap?

is it possible by

```
try
{
}
catch(err)
{
}
```

thanks in advance.

Kobi

Comment: logcat is just the logging system used by Android. It doesn't throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are asking how to print the log from Phonegap?
If so please take a look at this post :
[How to display console.log() output in PhoneGap app using Eclipse and HTC Desire HD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847290/how-to-display-console-log-output-in-phonegap-app-using-eclipse-and-htc-desire)