# JavaScript alert box not displaying on Android

Tags: javascript, android, browser

I can't seem to get a JS alert box to show up when using either browser (tested with Chrome and Android Browser) on Android (v 4.4). Might there be a system setting that prevents me from doing this? The reason I want to enable it is to do some quick debugging (not sure how to use console in a mobile web view). Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once checked `alert` they work fine in `Android`. But anyways if you want to use `console.log` in android web for `debugging` then use 1 of the following method

**Method 1**

Use [this tool](http://jsconsole.com/remote-debugging.html) it provides you console.log remotely ([Stack Overflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5910018/2385565))

**Method 2**

Another tool that is much simple is available at [GitHub](https://github.com/gorbiz/mobile-console.log) for mobile console

Comment: Thanks. Actually I just discovered that both browsers are caching an old footer section of the site, which doesn't include my updated script. Pulling my hair as to why it insists on caching this part since I've cleared cache and other data several times.