# android webview javascript invoke missing function

Tags: javascript, android, webview, android-webview

I need to catch an error when invoking javascript from android's webview; if the javascript is missing I need to catch some event and do something else in android instead.

for instance, I have webview.loadUrl("javascript:doSomething");

the page is missing 'doSomething', so I can see the following error in logcat:

ReferenceError: Can't find variable: doSomething ...

I need to catch this error and handle it, for instance something like

```
public override void onJsErrorReceived(String errorDescription)
{
    if(errorDescription.contains("doSomething"))
       handleError();
}
```

I can't find any such event in webview, nor in the clients of webview (WebChromeClient and WebViewClient) to overridel.

Does anybody have an idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4860021/android-problem-with-debugging-javascript-in-webview), the methods you need to over-ride are:

`WebChromeClient.onConsoleMessage(String message, int lineNumber, String sourceID)`

and

`WebChromeClient.onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage cm)`,