# How to bookmark HTML File loaded using WebView from assets?

Tags: android, html, webview, save

I have over 1000 HTML pages loaded on WebView. Below is a demo of my code and I want an option that can bookmark the page if user clicks on a specific button (perhaps bookmark icon in the webview). Let's say if page 45 was loaded on the screen and a user bookmarks it, then I want that page to be added in a ListView so a user can jump into that specific page.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/1.html");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok create a database that holds a list of strings. When the user clicks the button get the current URL and add it to that database. Use an adapter to populate your ListView from that database. Where is the problem there?

Refer to [Call Java function from JavaScript over Android WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10389572/call-java-function-from-javascript-over-android-webview) if you need that favourite button to be part of the HTML content (though I think this is a bad idea)