# Selected input doesn't work with Android

Tags: android, eclipse, html

I had created my **Android** App as it play sound when change select input option to **on**. I had created my interface to call android method in **html** . I did my code well but when I change the option value to **on** it doesn't work .

Play sound method:

```
public void playsound(String value ) {
    if (value == "on") {
    mp= MediaPlayer.create(mContext,R.raw.sound);

    /* mp.prepare();*/
    mp.start();
    }
}
```

```
<form >       
      <select name="flip-1" id="flip-1" data-role="slider" >
      <option value="off">Off</option>
      <option value="on" onclick="playmp3('on')">On</option>
      </select>

 <script type="text/javascript">
       function playmp3(var value) {
       Android.playsound(value);
       }  
</script>

</form >
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use the `onchange` event in the `select` element instead of the `onclick` event in the `option` element.

```
<select name="flip-1" id="flip-1" data-role="slider" onchange="f1()">
      <option value="off">Off</option>
      <option value="on" onclick="playmp3('on')">On</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function f1(){
      var myselect = document.getElementById("flip-1");
      playmp3(myselect.options[myselect.selectedIndex].value);
    }
</script>
```

Also, you have an error in your javascript method, the `var` keyword is not necessary:

```
 function playmp3(value) {
       Android.playsound(value);
 }
```

Comment: it worked but the default value "on" only it will work , i need the user will selected

Comment: @egydeveloper What do you mean? The listener function has to check the value of the inner option and call the `playmp3`. I have updated my answer to reflect this behaviour...

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if (value.equals("on")) {
mp= MediaPlayer.create(mContext,R.raw.sound);

/* mp.prepare();*/
mp.start();
}
```

Howto call Android method from JS take a look to this link:

[Call Android method from JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10389572/call-java-function-from-javascript-over-android-webview)

Comment: it doesn't worked also i tried to call the method without value but it didn't work

Comment: Is playSound part of the JavaScriptInterface? Anyhow... value == "on" cannot work. You have to change it to equals("on"). With == you compare the object reference not the value of your string.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (value.equals("on"))
{
   //Your code
}
```