# How to call android function using javascript / jquery in android webview?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, webview

I have tried pass the parameter from javascript to android but it return

```
01-08 20:32:17.214: D/WebConsole(27791): Uncaught Error: Error calling method on NPObject. -- From line 433 of file:///data/data/com.test/files/HK/news_list.html
```

My code is like the following

Js:

```
function changeSection(){
    //var pos = parseInt($(this).attr("data-index"),10);
    var pos = 2;
    if (pos == 3){
        window.location.href="video_list.html";
    } else {
        window.location.href="news_list.html?target="+$(this).attr("target")+"&type="+$(this).attr("type");
    }
    window.jsinterface.highLightLeftMenu(2);
}
```

The code that build up the button link:

```
    if(target+'_'+pageType == LMenu[k]['sid']){
        sectionMenu += "<div class='focus' data-index='"+k+"' target='"+tmpArr[0]+"' type='"+tmpArr[1]+"' onclick=\"changeSection()\">"+LMenu[k]['name']+"</div>";
    }else{
        sectionMenu += "<div data-index='"+k+"' onclick=\"changeSection()\">"+LMenu[k]['name']+"</div>";
    }
```

Android:

```
 mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "jsinterface");

public void highLightLeftMenu(int pos) {
        Log.d("test1","aa");
        Log.d("test1","bb" + pos);
        MainActivity.highLightLeftMenu(pos);
    }
```

It can log out the aa and bb with pos in android , but return the error message in the webview, also, how to pass the integer in js/jquery to android without hard coding ? thanks

Comment: I think [this][1] may help you out.
See Boris Strandjev's answer.

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10389572/call-java-function-from-javascript-over-android-webview