# How does one invoke a method in a .java file from a hybrid application

Tags: android, hybrid-mobile-app

I am very new to mobile development and i am trying out a few things on developing a hybrid application.

In my hybrid application, i have an index.html page where in have a link and when some clicks that link it calls a js function and i also have method in my explorer.java file lets call that method speakout().

I need to call this speakout method from my js function. Is there a way i can do it?

Comment: Try this if it helps you  

[call java function from javascript over android webview][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10389572/call-java-function-from-javascript-over-android-webview