# call android function from javascript

Tags: javascript, android

I want to create a button in html and make a call from that button from android through javascript. I have written the following code , which is not working :
I am beginner for android.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String PIC_WIDTH = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

        myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JsInterface(), "android");  
myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
}

public class JsInterface{  
        public void makeCall()
        {
            Log.i("Myactivity","inside android makecall");
            // Here call any of the public activity methods....
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:9611396958"));
            startActivity(callIntent);
        }
    }


}
```

in javascript :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

    <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />

</head>


    <body class="bgClass" id="body" ontouchstart="">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>   

    <script src="js/myScript.js"></script>
    <button id="makeCall" >CALL</button>
    <script>
      $("#makeCall").click(function(){
        console.log("inside click javascript");
        console.log(window.android);
        android.makeCall();
      });
      </script>
        </body>
</html>
```

any help??

Comment: You should take a look at Cordova and Sencha frameworks...

Comment: What does "not working" mean, are you getting error's in the console, is it doing anything, are print out's saying its getting so far etc.

Comment: when i click button nothing happens. It  says android is not defined

Comment: @SSS please post your full index.html , I am already in solving stage. so please post full html page from which this js called

Comment: I posted full index.html. see the edited code

Comment: yes I have seen. When I have added the webview you html page is blank. So do you want to call it automatically when it will load? or there will be any button ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44940/discussion-between-satyaki-mukherjee-and-sss)

Comment: <script src="js/myScript.js"></script--> become  <script src="js/myScript.js"></script> then it will show call button

Comment: that was a typo mistake

Comment: your problem in script. because I have tested the code, and call button does not have any sense .

Comment: possible duplicate of [call java function from javascript over android webview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10389572/call-java-function-from-javascript-over-android-webview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question so that it can help others .:)
Finally solved it :
`myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient());` it was missing so javascript was not working . And i must add `@JavascriptInterface` as Hardik Trivedi suggested above. 
It is working fine now.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your `$("#makeCall")` method is responding in html.

Then make below changes.It will work.

```
public class JsInterface{ 
        @JavascriptInterface
        public void makeCall()
        {
            Log.i("Myactivity","inside android makecall");
            // Here call any of the public activity methods....
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:9611396958"));
            startActivity(callIntent);
        }
    }
```

This annotation allows exposing methods to JavaScript.

Comment: If i do that it will give error as : JavascriptInterface cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: @JavascriptInterface is introduced in JellyBean.

You need to set the Project Build Target to API Level 17

From Eclipse IDE, go to Project->Properties. Select Android and set the target

The APK will work on older versions of android.

Comment: What this console.log("inside click javascript");
        console.log(window.android); two lines print ?

Comment: it prints inside click javascript. Then tells window.android is not defined

Comment: As far as I know there is nothing like window.android. Please remove that ? For what purpose you have written that line ?

Comment: ok removed it... Still nothing happens. Is my android part code correct??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44942/discussion-between-hardik-trivedi-and-sss)

Answer (score 0):

simply adding webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); worked for me.
must add @JavascriptInterface too.