# Calling Android Activity Method From HTML Button

Tags: android, html

i am trying to call a java method in androind activity from html button, loaded in webView but when i click the buton nothing happens. Here is the code i have tried

Here is the html code

```
 <button onClick="activity.TestMethod();">Call Java Activity Method</button>
```

Here is the android activity method

```
public void TestMethod()
  {
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "this is my Toast message!!! =)",
     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

  }
```

I have enabled JavaScript by using

```
 WebView index = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
 WebSettings webSettings = index.getSettings(); 
 webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 index.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Activity.java File

```
final MyJavaScriptInterface myJavaScriptInterface = new MyJavaScriptInterface(
                    this);
            webView.addJavascriptInterface(myJavaScriptInterface, "activity");

public class MyJavaScriptInterface {
        Context mContext;

    MyJavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    //Add @JavascriptInterface to call this method from > 4.2 Android Version
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void TestMethod() {

        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Hello from JavaScript Interface", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
    }
}
```

> HTML File

```
 <button onClick="jsMethod();">Call Java Activity Method</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
   function jsMethod(){
       activity.TestMethod();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: its giving syntax error in line 3 on "actvitiy" , it says " VariableDeclarator expected "

Answer (score 0):

You have to set up a `JavaScriptInterface` for the `WebView` first. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10389572/call-java-function-from-javascript-over-android-webview) for an example.

Comment: i have already done that please check the update in question. . .