# Android webview local html auto redirect to browser

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

I'm trying to automatically redirect from a local html file in an android web-view to a browser window when a cookie is read. The JavaScript below opens the URL in the web-view but I need it to open in a separate browser instead.

```
onload=function(){
    document.getElementById('linksNewWindow').checked = readCookie('linksNewWindow')==1? true : false;
    if(document.getElementById('linksNewWindow').checked = readCookie('linksNewWindow')== true){
        location.href = "url";
    }
}
```

The code for the android app just calls the local html file into the webview

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE.startsWith("4.4.2")) {

    String localUrl = "file:///android_asset/splash/splashKitkat.html";
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl(localUrl);          
}
```

I'm not sure if this is a small issue with my javascript or something bigger if someone could help me out that would be great.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javasctipt-Java bridge and call Android code from your custom HTML javascript inside WebView. That Android code may launch intent for the external browser. See more [Call Java function from JavaScript over Android WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10389572/call-java-function-from-javascript-over-android-webview)