# Programatically force webview go to fullscreen mode in android?

Tags: android, webview, youtube-javascript-api

I am developing the one app to load youtubevideos(YoutubeInstance of Javascript) on webview.all are playing well.But, i want show the webview fullscreen.presently not going to fullscreen.how can i force to fullscreen of landscape or portrait mode. please help me anyone known advance thanks to all.

see the below screenshot

[image]

Comment: try using    `getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` on that `Button` press

Comment: Not sure that is correct approach but you may create method in Android which will make activity fullscreen and stretch the webview. This method you may call from the javascript inside webview using custom javascript interface as described here http://stackoverflow.com/a/10389678/527759

Comment: requestFeature must be called before adding the content

Comment: that is not Button those are youtube controls@Himanshu Agarwal

Comment: Anyway you can use custom javascript and intercept that button click in some way.