# Can we use data from android to display it in webview using Javascript?

Tags: java, javascript, php, android, mysql

I have fetched data from Web Server using MySql and PHP with JSON parsing. And then I have stored the data in the arraylist. Now what I want to do is to create a WebView and insert those datas in html string as given below:

```
htmlData = "<html>"+
            "<head"+
            "<title>Model Question</title>"+
            "</head>"+
            "<body>"+
            "The question of "+"English is :<br />"+getfromServer.get(0).getData()[0]+ 
            "<br /><form>"+
            "Option[0]"+"<input type='radio' name='c0' /><br />"+
            "Option[1]"+"<input type='radio' name='c1' /><br />"+
            "Option[2]"+"<input type='radio' name='c2' /><br />"+
            "Option[3]"+"<input type='radio' name='c3' /><br />"+
            "</form>"+
            "</body>"+
            "</html>";
```

here the getfromServer is the ArrayList of type Question_answer which is defined as:

```
package com.example.mcahelper;

public class Question_answer {
    private String Question,Options[] = new String[4];
    public void setData(String...datas){
        Question = datas[0];
        Options[0]=datas[1];
        Options[1]=datas[2];
        Options[2]=datas[3];
        Options[3]=datas[4];
    }
    public String[] getData(){
        String datas[]= new String[5];
        datas[0] = Question;
        datas[1]=Options[0];
        datas[2]=Options[1];
        datas[3]=Options[2];
        datas[4]=Options[3];
        return datas;
   }
}
```

Now  i want to execute the loop to get every object of type Question_answer from the array list and put it in the string htmlData which will be further used as:

```
webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wbvw);
    WebSettings websettings = webview.getSettings();
    websettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);



    webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://bar", htmlData,"text/html", "utf-8", "");
```

Can we use javascript or is their any other way.
Please help.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply not loop over the list and use `StringBuilder` to construct your html string? However to answer your question it is possible to reference Java code from Javascript in `WebView`. See here for example [Call java code from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10389572/call-java-function-from-javascript-over-android-webview).