# how to get value of Class.js in android

Tags: java, android

i have a class model .js So, how to get value from this class in android project

```
class Polygon{
      constructor(height, width) {
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;
      }

      get area() {
        return this.calcArea();
      }

      calcArea() {
        return this.height * this.width;
      }
}
```

Comment: You can use a [`JavascriptInterface`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10389572/call-java-function-from-javascript-over-android-webview).

Comment: if not use for webview. how to get value of this  @KNeerajLal

Comment: How do you run the file without `WebView`?

Comment: yep. you know this solution? @KNeerajLal