# is it possible to close android/ios application webview using java script?

Tags: javascript, android, webview, line, chatbot

Basically i am opening a web page in Chat bot which is configured over Line messaging application for signup on auth server and after completing signup i tried to close web view using java script but not able to do this below is my code snippet for closing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <script>
        function close(){
         window.close(); 
        }
      </script>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>Test Webview Closing</title>
    </head>
    <body>
         <input type="button" value="test" onclick="close()">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What tool are you using to wrap the JS in native app?

Comment: i am using line api for Bot's in which they provide actions for opening url .
so i am opening web page via url  and js is wrap inside that  web page

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
WebChromeClient webClient = new WebChromeClient(){

public void onCloseWindow(Window w){
    super.onCloseWindow(w);
    Log.d(TAG, "Window close");
 }
};
```

add `webView.setWebChromeClient(webClient);` in your application web view code.

Answer (score 0):

you can call java Function from java script in which you can write logic of closing an app.. 
ref : https://stackoverflow.com/a/10389678/3746306