# It's possible to call an android app content provider from a web page using javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, android-contentprovider

I'm searching about how to expose some functionalities from my android app to a webpage using content provider.
My app stores digital certificates in AndroidKeyStore, i'd like to list this certificates on a webpage using js.

Comment: "some functionalities" like what specifically? anything that requires an android API -> no.

Comment: Basically, i'd like to know if there is a way to exchange information between android app and js.

Comment: using a database, yes. look at firebase

Comment: I wouldn't like to use a database, just to provide a way to return to js some data that only my app can access as my certificate list.

Comment: then no... you cant do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do it is using Android WebView and exposing some functions to javascript.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10389678/2004555

Answer (score 0):

You can do a native app, in java and c++ or an html app with cordova or similar. Content provider belong to native app world. If you need to work with them, i suggest you to build an native app (in java) and do user interface natively.