# How to get VectorDrawable path click listener event from imageview in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, svg, android-imageview, android-vectordrawable

I am showing one image view that showing a svg map. my requirement is to get particular svg path click event. i don't know what is the process or any idea about this scenario

this is my xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/richPathView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_map" />

    </HorizontalScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

this is my [svg](https://a.uguu.se/dTrMKcCP5Um6_svgfile.svg) map
please help me how should i get click event on click of svg path.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found [this](https://github.com/tarek360/RichPath) (RichPath) amazing library which allow me to detect path click

**class**

```
 richPathView.setOnPathClickListener { richPath ->
            if (richPath.name != null) {
                when {
                    richPath.name.toLowerCase() == "m" -> {
                        // my task
                    }
                    richPath.name.toLowerCase() == "e" -> {
                        // my task
                    }
            }
      }
```

**XML**

```
<HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true">
        <com.richpath.RichPathView
            android:id="@+id/richPathView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:vector="@drawable/ic_map" />

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

don't know this is valid right soluction or not but it's working.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  There is no way to determine which path in a VectorDrawable has been clicked on.  At least no easy way.

The only way I know of right now is to load the SVG into a WebView.  And then call a method in your Android app from Javascript.

[Call Java function from JavaScript over Android WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10389572/call-java-function-from-javascript-over-android-webview)