# android perform task on main tread (UI Thread) synchronous on main thread

Tags: javascript, android, webview

my question is related to this question:
[How to get return value from javascript in webview of android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298597/how-to-get-return-value-from-javascript-in-webview-of-android)

more precisely to this answer to it:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14817248/1816644

Unfortunately I am not allowed to comment on that answer, therefore I post this question.

I want to evaluate a javascript function, called from java.

The common solution to do this is to use a webView and a JavaScriptHandler or WebChromeClient.

In my case, I want to provide a method, that can be called from any thread ( including the UI Thread! ), which returns the result of the javascript evaluation.

This is also what the author from this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14817248/1816644  tried to accomplish.

He uses an android.os.Handler and posts the call to the javascript function on it. The problem is, that when this function is called from main thread, the posted call to the javascript function is executed AFTER the calling message has returned. But since I am waiting for the posted call to finish before I return, this never happens.

Comment: Event-driven programming has been in use for a couple of decades. Please use it, rather than attempting to force blocking calls.

Comment: I can't do this, since I have to implement a given Interface, which requires me to return a value.

Comment: Then do not use `WebView` as your JavaScript engine. Use Rhino, or V8 (https://code.google.com/p/jav8/), or something.

Comment: Can i use Rhino on android, too? I thought this wasn't possible since Rhino uses the java.lang.script package?

Comment: I experimented with Rhino back in 2009, and it worked (though then I had to fix up a `java.beans` dependency that should no longer be an issue). AFAIK the Java scripting code is optional.