# Webview and get data from form in android

Tags: android

I would like to know if possible is to get data from webview. I mean I have form in webview. I want to click submit in form in this webview and I want to get data from every field and save that data in database. This is possible?

Comment: To get data from a WebView in Android : https://stackoverflow.com/a/76415649/12272687

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible, use `addJavascriptInterface` in your webview, get click event using JS then call a android function  using javascript interface.

See [Binding JavaScript code to Android code](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#BindingJavaScript)

Comment: **This works for Android only.** The interface will also be called if the user is viewing from desktop or even an iPhone running iOS and cause an error. Any suggestion to a cross-platform method of doing this?