# Is there a way to get an image's title using Android's WebView?

Tags: android, image, webview, title

I am using Android's WebView as the rendering engine for a browser.  I would like to be able to get an image's title.  For example, when browsing to https://www.xkcd.com/327/ on a desktop, mousing over the comic displays the following text:  "Her daughter is named Help I'm trapped in a driver's license factory."  The source code for the comic is as follows:

```
<img src="//imgs.xkcd.com/comics/exploits_of_a_mom.png" title="Her daughter is named Help I&#39;m trapped in a driver&#39;s license factory." alt="Exploits of a Mom" />
```

Using [WebView.HitTestResult.getExtra()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.HitTestResult.html#getExtra()) pulls the `src`.  Does anyone know of a way to get the `title`?

Comment: you might try WebView.evaluateJavascript(), see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19788294/how-does-evaluatejavascript-work.  This might be challenging if you don't control the web content, but it allows you to run your own javascript code against the DOM and return data.

Comment: `WebView.evaluateJavascript()` is an interesting idea.  As you point out, implementing it is difficult if you don't control the web content.  In my case, I am building a browser that needs to be able to pull an image title from any image on any website and display it in a context menu.

Comment: I added a feature request to the Android project to add this functionality.  https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=231063