# Android Studio: Webview and Sessions Basics

Tags: android, webview

I have a webview that is working perfectly as follows:

```
    wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv);
    //Enable JavaScript
    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.setFocusable(true);
    wv.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    //Set Render Priority To High
    wv.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
    wv.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    wv.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    wv.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    wv.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    wv.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    //Load Url
    wv.loadUrl("https://str8red.com/");
```

I then have the following code which runs when a button is clicked:

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,"https://str8red.com/loggedincheck",

                    new Response.Listener<String>(){
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            textView.setText(response);
                            requestQueue.stop();
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    textView.setText("Something went wrong");
                    error.printStackTrace();
                    requestQueue.stop();
                }
            });
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
        }
    });
```

The address simply returns a string of "True" or "False" depending if the user is logged into the webview.  The good news is that it is returning a string but it is always returning False, even when I have logged in to my site using the webview. I know the address `https://str8red.com/loggedincheck` works as expected as it works both in a web browser and also in the iOS app.

I am assuming that when the button is clicked it is not using the the same webview and therefore has no idea if the user is logged in or not.

I have looked online for a solution but have come unstuck.  Any help would be appreciated.

If you need any additional information please do not hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed it will be always return false, because there is no relation between your `Volly` code and your `webView` code, so the right way based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20377857/6490462), you have to use `evaluateJavascript` instead of volley, by passing your `javaScript` function you can know user case.

```
wv.evaluateJavascript("(function() { return 'this'; })();", new ValueCallback<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onReceiveValue(String s) {
        Log.d("LogName", s); // Prints: "this"

        //check for user case based on javaScriptFunction
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok, so just have to use a different approach on android as opposed to iOS.  Appreciate the swift response.

Comment: I don't know if there an easier way, but the code won't able to have relation between webView and `volley` code.

Comment: That is ok,  I will remove the volley part.  So when they login I will just have some variables within javascript on that page and pass them back to the native app using wv.evaluateJavascript as described.  May even be a cleaner solution for the iOS version too.  I hope what I have said makes sense and means I have understood your response.

Comment: that is exactly what i mean best of luck.

Comment: Great news, and I am happy I understood.  Go me lol.  Take care Ibrahim.