# Android button as WebView click link for Logout (or delete sessionId)

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

In my WebView android, I want the user to logout on button click or any other way.
I don't want to show any webpage after clicking that button. After that app should auto-exit(System.exit(0) will do that)

Click I want to send is:

```
http://192.100.1.1:10000/app?service=direct/1/UserSummary/$UserBorder.logoutLink
```

What's the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason behind this question was this logout link has nothing to display. So I wanted something like click to logout. Simple Android button in Main Activity didn't help for this.

So, I created new `blank activity`, used same layout I was using, but instead of showing blank layout, I added `ProcessDialog` and made it non-cancel-able as follows:

```
    final ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(Logout.this);
    pd.setCancelable(false);
    pd.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    pd.setMessage("Please wait...");
    pd.show();
```

And in `public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)` method, I dismissed this ProcessDialog and fired an intent for login page of my app. Also overridden the `public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)` to prevent it from going to out of app.

After that, simply `webView.loadUrl(url);`.

This way I fixed my problem.
(If you know better and simpler way of doing it, please post.)

Answer (score 0):

Use Rest to make a get call to this URL.

To make it use an async task:

See an example [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

In your do in background do:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
    String url = urls[0];
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(getHttpParams());
    HttpResponse response = null;
    try {
        switch (taskType) {
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
        response = httpclient.execute(httpget);  
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
    }
    return response;
}

private HttpParams getHttpParams() {

    HttpParams htpp = new BasicHttpParams();

    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(htpp, CONN_TIMEOUT);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(htpp, SOCKET_TIMEOUT);

    return htpp;
}
```

Comment: Can you please give me an example? Do I need to import extra package for Rest APIs?

Comment: Sure, I'll try it soon. Thanks, I'll report status.

Comment: [@João Marcos](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3616148/jo%c3%a3o-marcos) There are lots of errors and deprecated methods in this. Can't resolve all of them.

Comment: After I pressed Alt+Enter to fix the imports and other errors, code was strikethrough and few variables remained in error (red colored text). I did rebuilding of project, but it didn't go away. I'm using Android Studio.