# Android/Webview: How to turn Observer pattern to a blocking function

Tags: android, multithreading, webview

In a webview, I would like to wrap two things in one blocking function:

I have the following:

```
public class WebBikeWebView extends WebView {

  private String mData;

  public WebBikeWebView(Context context) {
    super(context);

    // result of loadUrl() returns here in this call-back, in message
    this.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, final String message, JsResult result) {
            Log.d("LogTag", message);

            mData = message;

            result.confirm();
            return true;
        }
    });
  }


  // I would like to create a blocking method like this:
  public String getValue(final String name) {

    String code = "javascript:alert(' + " name + "')";

    this.loadUrl(code);

    ret = mData;   // problem is that mData is a result from the call-back onJsAlert()      

    return ret;
  }

}
```

I would like the `getValue()` method **to be a synchronous/blocking method**.

It's a bit like using wait/notify on the same thread. I did tried wait/notify, but the control stops fetching the data as this interrupts the current thread.

Comment: did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298597/how-to-get-return-value-from-javascript-in-webview-of-android

Comment: @rajath: this solution is not "blocking/synchronous"

Comment: maybe you can use the callback to do the work you need

Comment: @rajath: I tried but can't find any solution so far.. any solution is welcome! Thanks!