# How to pass a string value to a webview for eg : to youtube"

Tags: android, webview, youtube

Im just a beginner to android so had a doubt on if this is possible or not .

In my application i need to pass a string value into youtube site's search bar and the perform a search .

Instead of manually entering it into the Webview , can this be passed via code ?

Can this be made possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to do so, the first one is just passing the search query as a get parameter.

```
String query = "never gonna give you up";
webview.loadUrl("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + query);
```

The second, which might be more elegant would passing JS code that will preform the change.

```
webview.loadUrl("https://www.youtube.com");
// wait for it to load
webview.loadUrl("javascript:(function () { " + "<js code>" + "})()");
```

Comment: But usually , for eg i query for "taylor swift" , i get a youtube url of .

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=taylor+swift

How do you propose that i add in the "+" symbol instead of the space ?

Comment: agrTextView.getText().toString().replaceAll(" ", "+"); will do the work right ??

Comment: Okay , New task . 

In the webview as of now i get the result of my search.

Just assume that i have clicked on one of the result's .

How do i setup the activity to respond in such a manner that it has to listen to my click on the webview ..

Comment: For eg: I choose a search result , which directs me to the Video player page . , Instead i need to just get the url of that page passed into the activity back ..

Is that possible ?

Comment: Can we implement such a Listener?

Comment: you pass JS code that will perform the thing you want to do in the webview, and pass the data or the callback to your java code. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298597/how-to-get-return-value-from-javascript-in-webview-of-android/19077097#19077097