# How to get Javascript value into a Android activity

Tags: javascript, android

I am currently creating a application with the webview interface and i need to retrieve the var that is being stored in webview to the android activity

Here is the sample

```html
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script>
var testing="hello";
</script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

I need to get the Hello string from the script into some String variable under the Android Activity

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get return value from javascript in webview of android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298597/how-to-get-return-value-from-javascript-in-webview-of-android)

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#UsingJavaScript     see "binding"

Comment: binding refer to calling a method in android from the JS i need to get a value from JS to android