# How to return value from JS function to Java instantly without JS Interface?

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview

I have a webview. I want to call JS function from Java and assign return value to a variable.

This line from java calls getUserDetails() function of JavaScript.

```
webview.loadUrl("javascript:window.getUserDetails()");
```

This is the getUserDetails function in javascript which returns a string

```
window.getUserDetails = function(){
    return "username"; 
}
```

I want to achieve something like this.

```
String user = webview.loadUrl("javascript:window.getUserDetails()");
```

How can I able to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the way you are calling that method.

```
webview.loadUrl("javascript:alert(window.getUserDetails())");
```

and while handling the alert your returned value will be there.
For more info please follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298597/how-to-get-return-value-from-javascript-in-webview-of-android)

As per the comment you can do this in following way.

```
String  mUserName; 


String getUserName(){ 


runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {


webView.loadUrl("javascript:android.onData(window.getUserDetails())");

        }
    });

return mUserName;
}


@JavascriptInterface
public void onData(String value) {
   mUserName = value;
}
```

Comment: But I want to return that value instantly. 

I will use that line inside some function like this 

    public String getUser(){
        String user = webview.loadUrl("javascript:window.getUserDetails()");
        return user;
    }

Comment: @kiranpuppala, check out the new edit and see if thats what you are looking for?

Comment: But by the time mUserName gets returned, it wouldn't get initialized right. It will get initialized later in onData function.

Comment: Yup, so when you call `webView.loadUrl("javascript:android.onData(window.getUserDetails())");` it in return call onData method and then you will have mUserName field initialised and the returned value will have correct userName.

Comment: Can you read my comment properly. `getUserName()` function will not wait until `mUserName` gets initialized. It just calls
    `webView.loadUrl("javascript:android.onData(window.getUserDetails())");`
and returns null value of `mUserName` immediately.

Comment: then do this 
`runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
               webView.loadUrl("javascript:android.onData(window.getUserDetails())");
            }
        });`

Answer (score 0):

[WebView#evaluateJavascript](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#evaluateJavascript(java.lang.String,%20android.webkit.ValueCallback%3Cjava.lang.String%3E)) is the recommended way to do this asynchronously. If you want something which feels synchronous, you can try using `Future`s to wait for the callback:

```java
final SettableFuture<String> jsFuture = SettableFuture<>.create();
webView.evaluateJavaScript("window.getUserDetails()", new ValueCallback<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onReceiveValue(String value) {
        jsFuture.set(value);
    }
});
String value = jsFuture.get();
```