# How to escape from a WebView

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios, webview

I'm currently advertising my web with Google AdWords and my web is displayed on different mobile apps, when people click the banner, the app open a WebView. I use cookies to sign in the user through the mobile company number. And almost all of the apps have the Web View with the DOMStorsge off and there's no way to store de session with a cookie, because of this.

I want to get out of the app WebView and go to the "browser" app
There's anything i can do? A onLoad href="browser:www......"

All of this is for opening the web from Android and iOS.

Thanks

Comment: You can get a callback from the WebView to your App: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298597/how-to-get-return-value-from-javascript-in-webview-of-android From that you can create an Intent to open the Default Browser of the phone.

Comment: Yes but we have 0 control about those apps, if i was able to modify the WebView that would be awesome. They only display my banner from Google Adwords with a webview. And I wan't to scape from the other company app WebView to my website with the default mobile browser that your'e using.