# Get value from input in android webview

Tags: javascript, java, android, html, webview

So I tried to get the value of an input type into a string in my android webview. But I couldnt find a way. Below is my code in the html.

```
<input class="input100"  type="hidden" id="captcha1" name="captcha1" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['captcha']; ?>">
```

And i wanted to get the value and store it into a string in my android webview. Any clue??

Comment: At which moment do you want to grab those values? What is the action the user has to take?

Comment: As soon as I load the URL, I want to get the value.

Answer (score 1):

You have to register javascript interface to webview. You can add methods with annotaion @JavascriptInterface to android webview controller that can be called from Webview controll. Also don't forgate to remove those from proguard...
for more info [How to get return value from javascript in WebView of Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298597/how-to-get-return-value-from-javascript-in-webview-of-android)
**This example will read from html text and put in android text view.**
***You should be always carefullwhile exposing android method to webview java script***

```
import android.content.Context
import android.util.Log
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
import android.webkit.WebView
import android.widget.TextView

class MyWebView(context:Context, textView: TextView) {
var outValue:String =""
val myWebView = WebView(context)
val html: String by lazy{"<!DOCTYPE html><head><title>Loading...</title></head><body>"+
        "<input  type=\"text\" id=\"captcha1\" name=\"captcha1\" onkeyup=\"fromAndroid.getData(value);\">"+
        "<img src= /></body></html>"}

init {
    val javaScriptInterface = object: JavaScriptInterface{
        @JavascriptInterface
        override fun getData(data: String){
            outValue = data
            textView.text = data
            Log.d(TAG, data)
        }
    }
    myWebView.settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true)
    myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(javaScriptInterface, "fromAndroid")
    myWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", html, "text/html","UTF-8", null);
}
companion object{
    const val TAG = "MyWebView"
}
}

interface JavaScriptInterface{
  fun getData(data: String)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something similar in your code, The function from javascript must return the value and then it will be caught here as follows:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        // webView referenced from layout id
        webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webView.webViewClient = MyWebViewClient()
        webView.setWebChromeClient(MyWebChromeClient())
        webView.loadUrl("http://foobar.com")
    }
    
    private class MyWebViewClient : WebViewClient() {
        override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView, url: String) {
            //functionToReturnSomething() should be \ same as you mention in javascript
            view.loadUrl("javascript:alert(functionToReturnSomething())")
        }

        override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView, url: String): Boolean {
            return false
        }
    }
    
    private class MyWebChromeClient : WebChromeClient() {
        override fun onJsAlert(view: WebView, url: String, message: String, result: JsResult): Boolean {
            result.confirm()
            return true
        }
    }
```